# SQL Union only counting one query

Tags: php, sql, database, union

Im trying to count rows in a table. Currently im using this:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM `friends` 
        WHERE `user1`='".$user1."' 
            AND `user2`='".$user2."' 
            AND `valid`=0 
        UNION 
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM `friends` 
        WHERE `user1`='".$user2."' 
            AND `user2`='".$user1."' 
            AND `valid`=0";
```

As you see, `user1` can be both `$user1` AND `$user2`. but it does not count the rows after the `UNION`, it only does the first query before `UNION` so im ending up with 0 when i actually should be counting 1 row.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another alternative, replace your query with this:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM `friends` 
    WHERE (
            (`user1`='".$user1."' AND `user2`='".$user2."') OR
            (`user1`='".$user2."' AND `user2`='".$user1."')
          )
     AND `valid`=0";
```

Comment: It depends if the OP wants a `1` or `2` if both queries return a record. If the former, your solution is ideal. If the latter, not so much

Comment: @Chandu but the other way around - very true. Incidentally, that's why I +1'd you. I thought my answer was closer to OP's actual request but your is far more elegant (and obviously superior) if the OP doesn't actually want to count twice.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is actually returning 2 records - `0` for the first count and `1` for the second. You could use a sub-query to `SUM()` your results...

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(A) AS COUNT FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS A
        FROM `friends` 
        WHERE `user1`='".$user1."' 
            AND `user2`='".$user2."' 
            AND `valid`=0 
        UNION 
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM `friends` 
        WHERE `user1`='".$user2."' 
            AND `user2`='".$user1."' 
            AND `valid`=0
)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL` instead. `UNION` will exclude duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an even simpler solution:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM friends
WHERE 
    $user1 IN (user1,user2) AND 
    $user2 IN (user1,user2) AND
    valid = 0
```

Comment: That would allow both $user1 and $user2 to have the same value.

Comment: @shawnt00 It wouldn't make sense to have the input parameters as the same value. If you look close, for each row, $user1 has to be in ***either*** of the columns... **AND** $user2 *ALSO* has to be in either of the columns. A single column can't contain two different users, so it's basically retrieving on the condition that both users are in `user1` and `user2` columns, but in either order, which is what the OP wants.

Comment: Your condition is equivalent to this: $user1 = 'user1' and $user2 = 'user1' OR $user1 = 'user2' and $user2 = 'user2' OR $user1 = 'user2' and $user2 = 'user1' OR $user1 = 'user2' and $user2 = 'user2'. Notice how that's not the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: As long as the table contains no rows where userX is his own friend then everything's fine. But add such row and it will be counted when $user_ = 'userX' and the other parameter "makes sense" as something entirely different.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the query. In my mind I was reversing the parameters and columns. So my comments were basically true, but do not apply to your answer. I would suggest the names might warrant a little more clarity to avoid the same mistake I made.